# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400

Tags: php, xml, yahoo-api

I have a class

```
class exchange_rates{

    var $currency = '"USDINR","TRYINR","SARINR","EURINR"'; 
    var $url ;
    var $handle;
    var $result;
    var $xml_index , $xml_val;

    public function __construct(){

            $this->url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ('.$this->currency.')&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys';


    }

    public function fetch_Currency (){ 

            //echo $this->url ;
            $this->handle = file_get_contents($this->url);

            if ($this->handle) {
                    $this->result = fgets($this->handle, 4096);
                    $p = xml_parser_create();

                    xml_parse_into_struct($p, $this->result, $this->xml_val, $this->xml_index);

                    xml_parser_free($p);

                    fclose($this->handle);
        }
    }

    public function get_exchange(){
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($this->xml_val);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

}
```

I am calling the class like this

```
$obj = new exchange_rates();
    $obj->fetch_Currency();
    $obj->get_exchange();
```

The error I am getting is as follow

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("USDINR","TRYINR","SARINR","EURINR")&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Unknown Version in C:\xampp\htdocs\ycc\currency_convertor.php on line 21
NULL
```

Basically I am trying to get the XML from the URL . If you parse the following url

```
 http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("USDINR","TRYINR","SARINR","EURINR")&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

You will see the XML result , But Through my code I am not able to download

Please help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this question when I was debugging the same thing. The solution for me was you have to urlencode the query part of the URL.

```
$query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("USDINR","TRYINR","SARINR","EURINR")';
$request = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' . urlencode($query) . '&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys';

$data = file_get_contents($request);
```

Hope this helps someone!

More info: https://developer.yahoo.com/php/howto-reqRestPhp.html